# Is there a way of returning data which is the closest to a single given value from a database?

Tags: sql

I'm creating a database which will have a series of prices of products in, I want to test out some queries, one of which is 'Find the product with the closest price to £100,000'. How would I write this query?

The product table name is 'Vehicles' and the price table name is 'Price'

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two different products with the same, closest price?

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `order by` using an expression:

```
select t.*
from t
order by abs(price - 100000)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

The `fetch` clause is standard SQL to limit the result set to one row.  Some databases use other constructs, such as `select top (1)` and `limit`).

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for if you're using SQL server:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM [myTable] 
    ORDER BY ABS( price - 100000 )
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Fair, question doesn't specify which dbms either. Edited though